# How to specify PORT on NPM start for webpack5

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I would like to run my react app on specific port.
With Webpack4 I can use `npm start -- --port 3361` which run my local app on port 3361.
But by updating it to Webpack5 now this command is not working and return me an error in terminal (I m using Mac) `[webpack-cli] Unknown option '--port'`.
Any help would be appreciated?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the `npm start` script looks like?

Comment: Can you post your `package.json`?